# recall vs precision graph

Tags: matplotlib, plot, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to plot a graph for precision vs recall this is my classification report. i don't know how to plot a graph displaying these.
this is my code for classification report

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print("")
print("Confusion Matrix")
print(confusion_matrix(Y_test, predictions))
print("")
print("Classification Report                                XGBOOST")
print(classification_report(predictions,Y_test))
```

output:

```
Confusion Matrix
[[1163   55]
 [  46  665]]

Classification Report                                 xgboost
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.95      0.96      0.96      1209
           1       0.94      0.92      0.93       720

    accuracy                           0.95      1929
   macro avg       0.95      0.94      0.94      1929
weighted avg       0.95      0.95      0.95      1929
```

i'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

visulise my precision and recall using a graph.

Comment: Have a look at [`sklearn.metrics.roc_curve`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(Y_test,predictions)
plt.step(recall, precision, color='b', alpha=0.2,
         where='post')
plt.fill_between(recall, precision, alpha=0.2, color='b')
plt.xlabel('Recall')
plt.ylabel('Precision')
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
```

Try this.